# Sort/order a slice string by given slice

Tags: go

How do I sort a slice of string in a order that is given by another slice of strings. If that string is not there in the input slice then just ignore it.

```
animalsInput := []string{"cat", "bird", "zebra", "fox"}
animalsOrder := []string{"bird", "lion", "fox"}

//desired output
//{"bird", "fox", "cat", "zebra"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you can implement this is by writing a `rank` map based on the order array

```
rank:=map[string]int{}
for i, x:=range animalsOrder {
   rank[x]=i
}
```

Then use `rank` in `sort`:

```
sort.Slice(animalsInput,func(i,j int) bool {
  irank, ok:=rank[animalsInput[i]]
  if !ok {
      irank=len(animalsInput)
  }
  jrank, ok:=rank[animalsInput[j]]
  if !ok {
      jrank=len(animalsInput)
  }
  return irank<jrank
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func sort(in, order []string) (out []string) {
    flag := make([]bool, len(in))
    out = make([]string, len(in))
    orderCountMap := make(map[string]int)
    for i := range in {
        orderCountMap[in[i]] += 1
    }
    for i := range in {
        if _, found := orderCountMap[in[i]]; found {
            flag[i] = true
        } else {
            flag[i] = false
        }
    }
    p := 0
    for i := range order {
        if v, found := orderCountMap[order[i]]; found {
            for j := 0; j < v; j++ {
                out[p] = order[i]
                p += 1
            }
        }
    }
    for i := range flag {
        if !flag[i] {
            out[p] = in[i]
            p += 1
        }
    }
    return
}

func main(){
    animalsInput := []string{"cat", "bird", "zebra", "fox"}
    animalsOrder := []string{"bird", "lion", "fox", "zebra", "cat"}
    out := sort(animalsInput, animalsOrder)
    fmt.Println(out)
}
```

Comment: Hi, it fails for animalsOrder := []string{"bird", "lion", "fox", "zebra", "cat"}

Comment: Oh, sorry, I make a mistake.

Comment: After updating the `sort` function, it will work perfectly.@RajSharma